# Is a Vuzix Wrap 920 VR compatible with Counter-Strike: Source?

Tags: counter-strike-source

Is it possible turn my head independently from the weapons aiming point with the [Vuzix bundle](http://www.vuzix.com/consumer/products_wrap920vrbundle.html) in Counter-Strike: Source or does it act directly as a mouse?

Comment: Another good question would be if VAC won't identify Vuzix Extension as a hack?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about the Vuzix, but I do know that the engine Counter-Strike: Source runs on does not support moving the viewpoint without moving the crosshair.

So while the game is listed as a supported title, I would assume the crosshair (aiming point) is moved along with the view.

Comment: Is there no mod or tweak which can be done to move head and crosshair separated from each other?

Comment: Could you tell us the motivation behind your wish? In CS, you normally shoot at things that lie on your cross hair, not watch the scenery. Is this perhaps about a mod and not directly CS:S?